# opc-ua node-red: how to subscribe to a datasource?

Tags: node-red, opc-ua

With a node-red OPC UA Client node (from OPC UA contrib and not the IIOT OPC UA contrib package) I configured the action to be "subscribe" with update of 2 seconds. Then I inject 5 different opc ua item nodes. That results in 5 different, but correct, values in the debug output. And then nothing happens furthermore. I was expecting that each 2 seconds I would see 5 new values. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do the values change on OPC UA Server after the first output on client-side?

Answer (score 0):

When you begin the flow, the subscription will generate a debug event.  It will say something like "OpcUaClientNode: Monitoring Event: ns=2;s=... by interval of 153237375167 ms".  In my case, I actually specified an interval of 500ms (I've also tried 10ms, 100ms, 1 second and 10 seconds), but they always want to subscribe with the interval of 153237375167 ms.

While looking through the source, I found the answer... The client was ignoring the specified interval value and using the value from the injector (start of the flow).  In my case, it was configured as a timestamp.  I replaced the timestamp with a number value of 100 and it is working now with an interval of 100ms.